# How to change text link color for IOS

Tags: html, css

I have found a problem in text link color actually i set my link color is red for desktop view. Now when i saw in Iphone then the color change into blue. I use `!important` after color code but same result this time please tell me what is the problem and give me best solution.

Comment: Have you written media query for Responsive design?

Comment: sorry yes i use media query for only tab

Answer (score 0):

can u add "-webkit-appearance: none;" to the anchor tag, and set the font color and remove important from your code

eg:

```
.link {
   color: blue;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found my solution for this problem when i use this type of meta tag my text link color same as i described in css.

I use this meta tag in header.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: The given meta tag is only used to enable / disable phone numbers in a web page in safari on iOS. For reference check this [url](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
@media (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:768px) 
{
  a {color:#ff0000;}
}
```

If above code is not working for you a very well detailed following code may fix your problem which is given below.

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
      a {
        color: #ff0000;
      }

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 
      a {
        color: #ff0000;
      }

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
    a {
        color: #ff0000;
      }

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
      a {
        color: #ff0000;
      }

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 
      a {
        color: #ff0000;
      }
}
```

Comment: i use this type of code already in my css but i not fix this problem.

Comment: Check it and let me know

Answer (score -1):

You should have something like

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {
   a {
      color: red;
   }
}
```